# In what way was King Shlomo greater than Moshe?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, king-solomon

King Shlomo is known as the "smartest man" who ever lived (I Kings 3:12), while Moshe is known as the "greatest prophet" (Deuteronomy 34:10). But in Mishlei (30:1-4), King Shlomo seems to be praising Moshe's wisdom, as if his own wisdom is secondary to that of Moshe. In which realms did each prevail: was King Shlomo greater in wisdom, and Moshe in closeness to God? What exactly is the overlap of their talents?

Comment: I edited in the sources for you. Feel free to edit the formatting if you’d like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking of Shlomo the verse says:

**I Kings 5:11**

> וַיֶּחְכַּם מִכָּל הָאָדָם מֵאֵיתָן הָאֶזְרָחִי וְהֵימָן וְכַלְכֹּל
>   וְדַרְדַּע בְּנֵי מָחוֹל וַיְהִי שְׁמוֹ בְכָל הַגּוֹיִם סָבִיב
>
> For he was wiser than all men: than Ethan the Ezrahite, and Heman, and
>   Calcol, and Darda, the sons of Mahol; and his fame was in all the
>   nations round about. ([Mechon Mamre](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a05.htm))

However, the Talmud seems to imply that Moshe was greater in wisdom:

**[Megillah 13a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=13&format=pdf)** (My emphasis)

> ירד זה משה ולמה נקרא שמו ירד שירד להם לישראל מן בימיו גדור שגדר
>   פרצותיהן של ישראל חבר שחיבר את ישראל לאביהן שבשמים סוכו שנעשה להם
>   לישראל כסוכה יקותיאל שקוו ישראל לאל בימיו זנוח שהזניח עונותיהן של
>   ישראל אבי אבי אבי אב בתורה **אב בחכמה** אב בנביאות
>
> ‘Jered’: this is Moses. Why was he called Jered? Because manna came
>   down [yarad] for Israel in his days. ‘Gedor": [he was so called]
>   because he fenced in [gadar] the breaches of Israel. ‘Heber’, because
>   he joined [hiber] Israel to their Father in heaven. ‘Socho’, because
>   he was like a sheltering booth [sukkah] for Israel. ‘Jekuthiel’,
>   because Israel trusted in God [kiwu le'el] in his days. ‘Zanoah’,
>   because he made Israel abandon [hizniah] their inquities. ‘Father of’,
>   ‘father of’, ‘father of’: he was a father in Torah, **a father in
>   wisdom**, a father in prophecy. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf))

[R. Ashtori Haparchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtori_Haparchi) resolves this by saying that Moshe was certainly the greatest in wisdom. The verse which speaks about Shlomo is not including Moshe. Rather, it just means that Shlomo had the greatest wisdom of anyone in his generation.

He goes on to explain that there are different areas of wisdom and that in individual areas it is possible that Moshe was exceeded.

**Kaftor V'Ferach Chapter 44**

> ולזה נראה שאמרו על משה רבינו ע"ה אב בתורה אב בחכמה אב בנביאים מסכת
>   מגלה  ומה שנאמר על שלמה  ויחכם מכל האדם כבר אמרו ולא ממשה ר"ל מכל האדם
>   שבדורו אבל שבח משה רבינו מכל האדם אשר על פני האדמה כלומר שאין אפשרות
>   באדמה שימצא כמוהו וזה אינו תלוי לא בדור ולא בחלק מחלקי העולם ואין
>   להקשות ממה שכתוב הנה נתתי לך לב חכם ונבון אשר כמוך לא היה לפניך ואחריך
>   לא יקום כמוך שהרי מיני החכמה רבים וחכמת משה רבינו ע"ה עקרה באלהית כי
>   שליח היה לאל ית' בינו ובין ישראל להודיעם מצותיו חקותיו ותורותיו
>   ומיתרון הדביקות לא היה יכול להשקיף כל כך במפורסמות ועצת יתרו אליו ע"ה
>   יוכיח אבל חכמת שלמה ע"ה עקרה להעמיד חקי האלהים על תלם ולהיות מלך במשפט
>   ואמת ולהנהיג העם ביושר ולזה נאמר כזה הלשון על יוסף הצדיק אין נבון וחכם
>   כמוך וכן רק עם חכם ונבון הגוי הגדול הזה ואף על פי שחכמתו גם במושכלות
>   עד שעשו ז"ל ספרו קדש קדשים אבל על משה רבינו ע"ה לא קם נביא מושך עצמו
>   וחכמה וגבורה עמו והרמב"ם ז"ל כתב שאין מדריגת שלמה כמדרגת ישעיה וכבר
>   ידעת מה בין נביא ומדבר ברוח הקודש גם ידעת שלא הגיע ולא יגיע נביא
>   לנבואת אדון הנביאים אדוננו משה ע"ה וכמו שביארנו בפתיחת הספר

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79912/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-in-what-way-was-king-shlomo-greater-than-moshe).